# why does my daughter wake up in pain clawing at herself?

Tags: toddler

My daughter is 2 1/2 coming up three in a few months and she occasionally wakes up screaming in pain saying she hurts in her private area and claws at herself, she cant seem to stay still and seems to be in a lot of pain. I've tried everything to talk her and nothing works, sometimes I'm up for hours with her. it isn't in a routine as such just every couple of weeks or months apart. anyone have any idea what it could be, I'm very worried.

Comment: Have you talked to a doctor about this yet? Also, is this something that only happens at night and not at all during the day?

Answer (score 7):

As Mary Jo says, **let a doctor evaluate this.** This site is useful for parenting advice but your situation sounds like a medical condition and you should not blindly trust medical advice you read online.

It could be a fungus or an inflammation; that can itch or even give a burning sensation. Not uncommon with kids, especially if she still uses a diaper. That's easily treated with an ointment, but the doctor will know how to help.

Answer (score 4):

You should have your daughter evaluated by your doctor, as it could be any of a number of things. Start a journal where you log her symptoms by date, what time they start and when they subside, and any details you notice. The more information you have, the easier it will be for your doctor to make a diagnosis.